# MS sql server looping through huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

I have a table with 9 million record I need to loop through each row and need to insert into multiple tables in each iteration.

My example query is

```
//this is the table with 9 million records
create table tablename
(
   ROWID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) primary key ,
    LeadID int,
Title varchar(20),
FirstName varchar(50),
MiddleName varchar(20),
Surname varchar(50)
)


declare @counter int
declare @leadid int
Declare @totalcounter int

set @counter = 1
Select @totalcounter = count(id) from tablename
while(@counter < @totalcounter)
  begin
     select @leadid = leadid  from tablename
     where ROWID = @counter

     --perform some insert into multiple tables
     --in each iteration i need to do this as well
     select * from [sometable] 
       inner join  tablename where leadid = @leadid

      set @counter = @counter + 1
   end
```

The problem here is this is taking too long especially the join on each iteration.

Can someone please help me to optimize this.

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve. Why isn't a simple join enough? Why the loop and the counters?

Comment: Ideally, you express the operations in a set-based fashion and avoid looping at all. But we can't help with that at the moment because all you're showing us is your looping infrastructure code.

Comment: What is this query with `INNER JOIN` for????? It makes sense only on the last iteration - if your Stored Procedure returns it as a result set

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your join is taking long because there is no join condition specified between your two tables so you are creating a Cartesian product. That is definitely going to take a while.

If yuo want to optimize this, specifiy what you want to join those tables on.

If it is still slow, have a look at appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find all the rows in `sometable` that have the same `leadid` as the rows in `tablename` ? If so, a simple join should work

```
select t2.*
from tablename t2 inner join sometable t2
     on t1.leadid=t2.leadid
```

As long as you have an index on leaid you shouldn't have any problems

What are you really trying to do?